# PayPal IPN sandbox URL is currently down?

Tags: python, paypal

It seems that "https://sandbox.ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" is not responding? I'm trying to post sandbox IPN notifications to it to verify them. It was working fine yesterday, but today I'm getting an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sandbox.ipnpb.paypal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cgi-bin/webscr (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe126046450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

Answer (score 0):

"Name or service not known" is a DNS problem; that host does not exist

You are probably looking for **ipnpb.sandbox**.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr , which is [what is documented](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/)